# Component spinner not working

Tags: react-native, progress-bar, components

i create a component call Spinner so:

//spinner.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
    Image,
    StyleSheet,
    View,
    Text,
    KeyboardAvoidingView,
    TouchableHighlight,
    Modal,
    Button,
    ActivityIndicator,
} from 'react-native';

export default class Spinner extends Component{

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
        visible:this.props.visible
    };
    this._show=this._show.bind(this);
    this._hide=this._hide.bind(this);
}

render(){
    return(
        <Modal
            animationType={'none'}
            transparent={true}
            visible={this.state.visible}
            onRequestClose={this.props.onDismissLoadingCallback}>
            <View style={{flex:1}}/>
            <View style={{
                height:80,
                width:80,
                alignItems:'center',
                justifyContent:'center',
                backgroundColor:'#3434347f',
                borderRadius:10,alignSelf:'center'}}>
                <ActivityIndicator
                    animating={true}
                    size={"large"}
                    color={'white'}
                />
            </View>
            <View style={{flex:1}}/>
        </Modal>
    );
}
_show() {
this.setState({visible:true});
}

_hide(){
this.setState({visible:false});
}
}
```

in this create methods _show() and _hide()

but no working when is called from other class, i call from class Login.js

```js
class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { visible: false };
    }

_onLoginPress() {
        this.Spinner._show()
            )
    }  

 _redirect() {
       this.Spinner._hide()
    }
        render() {
                return (
         <Spinner visible= {this.state.visible}/>
         <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button}
                    onPress={this._onLoginPress}
                    activeOpacity={1} >
             <Text style={styles.textButtonLogin}>Visible</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>

          <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button}
                  onPress={this._redirect}
                  activeOpacity={1} >
            <Text style={styles.textButtonLogin}>Not Visible</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>

)
}
```

when set true in the constructor it if show, but when set false in the constructor it not show, it could show when press button _onLoginPress, and not show when is pressed button _redirect().

Comment: Why don't you directly pass the 'visible' prop to your modal in the Spinner component and in your Login component update the visible state instead of calling the show and hide? It is usually better avoid using refs when you can and use state and peops instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For using `<Spinner />` reference correctly, you have to

```js
<Spinner ref={(ref) => this.Spinner = ref} visible= {this.state.visible} />
```

And then your `this.Spinner._show()`, `this.Spinner._hide()` should work.